# How do I Increment timestamp in a column in the dataframe within a certain timerange

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a requirement where I have to increment and add timestamp to a `startTime` columns having same `areaId`.

Now I have different sets `areadId`, and initially only one row of each `areadId` has timestamps across `startTime1` to `startTime4`.

Now, we have to add the value given in `waterDuration` successively to other rows which are set to 00:00:00.

This is how my dataframe looks like before : -

```py
df.head(5).to_dict()
```

```
{'scheduleId': {0: 1069, 1: 1171, 2: 1134, 3: 1204, 4: 1185},
 'scheduleName': {0: 'Schedule 11',
  1: 'Scheule 10',
  2: 'test',
  3: 'Schedule 20',
  4: 'test2'},
 'areaId': {0: '125659657',
  1: '125659657',
  2: '125659657',
  3: '125659657',
  4: '125659657'},
 'deviceId': {0: '26513956',
  1: '26513956',
  2: '26611081',
  3: '26513956',
  4: '26611081'},
 'stationDeviceId': {0: '18634817',
  1: '18634819',
  2: '18634814',
  3: '18634816',
  4: '18634812'},
 'evStatus': {0: 'on', 1: 'on', 2: 'on', 3: 'on', 4: 'on'},
 'waterDuration': {0: 20, 1: 20, 2: 20, 3: 20, 4: 20},
 'noOfCyles': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 4},
 'startTime1': {0: datetime.time(0, 3),
  1: datetime.time(0, 0),
  2: datetime.time(0, 0),
  3: datetime.time(0, 0),
  4: datetime.time(0, 0)},
 'startTime2': {0: datetime.time(4, 4),
  1: datetime.time(0, 0),
  2: datetime.time(0, 0),
  3: datetime.time(0, 0),
  4: datetime.time(0, 0)},
 'startTime3': {0: datetime.time(8, 3),
  1: datetime.time(0, 0),
  2: datetime.time(0, 0),
  3: datetime.time(0, 0),
  4: datetime.time(0, 0)},
 'startTime4': {0: datetime.time(17, 0),
  1: datetime.time(0, 0),
  2: datetime.time(0, 0),
  3: datetime.time(0, 0),
  4: datetime.time(0, 0)},
 'waterPlanning': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None},
 'lastUpdatedTime': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None}}
```

After implementing the below code : -

```py
df.waterDuration = df.waterDuration.astype(int)

def add_from_last_row(row, timer):
    # If first row, nothing to do
    # row.name corresponds to the DataFrame index
    if row.name == 0:
        if timer == "startTime1":
            return row.startTime1
        if timer == "startTime2":
            return row.startTime2
        if timer == "startTime3":
            return row.startTime3
        if timer == "startTime4":
            return row.startTime4
    # If prev. row is not the same area, do nothing
    if row.areaId != df.loc[row.name-1, 'areaId']:
        if timer == "startTime1":
            return row.startTime1
        if timer == "startTime2":
            return row.startTime2
        if timer == "startTime3":
            return row.startTime3
        if timer == "startTime4":
            return row.startTime4

    # Get the min index in order to get the original startTime
    min_index = df[df.areaId == row.areaId].index.min()
    # Here we get the original startTime, cast to datetime
    default_time = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[min_index, timer], format="%H:%M:%S")
    # Sum all durations from min_index+1 to current row index
    seconds_to_add = df.loc[min_index+1:row.name, 'waterDuration'].sum()
    # Calculate the offset in seconds
    offset = pd.DateOffset(minutes=int(seconds_to_add))

    # return the last 8 character ie. hh:mm:ss
    # otherwise it would be YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
    return str(default_time + offset)[-8:]

for idx in range(4):
    st_time = 'startTime'+str(idx+1)
    df['startTime'+str(idx+1)]=df.apply(lambda x: add_from_last_row(x, st_time), axis=1)

df.loc[:, ['areaId', 'waterDuration', 'startTime1', 'startTime2', 'startTime3', 'startTime4']].head(20).sort_index(axis=0)
```

gives me the following dataframe : -

[image]

My requirement is that each `startTime` can only be set within a range of 4 hours for each unique `areadId`

So for example if `areaId : 125659657` `startTime1` starts from `00:03:00` it can only increment within 4 hour range such that for any record in `125659657`,  if the `startTime1` is to exceed the `04:00:00` mark it should be assigned the very first value which was `00:03:00` and again start incrementing from there for rest of the values in the column.

The 4 hour range starts from rounding off the first value in `startTime` columns to their nearest hour value. So for `startTime1` the range would be `00:00:00` to `04:00:00`. For `startTime2` it would be `04:00:00` to `08:00:00` and so on...

The starting value of each `startTime` is already set for each type of `areaId`. Also its not necessary that the start value will always be the same, just the range should be of maximum 4 hours.

**Expected Result : -**

[image]
.....................
.....................

Now, once if it reaches it's maximum allowed range of 4 hours, the next timestamps should reset to the initial timestamp and start incrementing from there again, such as :

[image]

Comment: @Laurent Sure, let me update my question.

Comment: @Laurent updated my question, do let me know if any other detail is needed.